# How to setup a proxy to a non-secure server for XMLHTTPRequests

Tags: nginx, xmlhttprequest, browser-security

I have a bunch of hosts that are raw IP's running HTTP. I have an app that uses WebAssembly with SharedArrayBuffer and thus must be served via HTTPS. This app needs to make requests to the hosts running on HTTP, but any XMLHTTPRequests are blocked due to browser security. Is there a simple way that I can proxy the HTTP sites through HTTPS?

Comment: You might have another issue with your queries https->http queries from JavaScript engine may be considered unsafe by many modern browsers. Also there might be a problem if you are sending queries from one domain to another or even raw IP.

Comment: Exactly, that is the issue I am trying to get around by using a proxy HTTPS. I just don't know what to use for that.

Comment: To get around of all these problems you need to sent https queries between same domains, otherwise you will get headache with header parameters, server settings, etc. But https to https is a key, avoid sending any data using unencrypted connection.